# Regex to allow space between numbers or nothing before the first one

Tags: java, regex, spring

I have the method that follows - `verifyPhones`, I am using two regexs on it.
The first one is to identify if the String is valid, if not I need to search which numbers are not valid.

My problem is when I have two valid numbers together - `20255501252025550125`, the system is returning only one of them as wrong instead of the whole string.

How can I improve my regex to have achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

**Definition of valid number:**

Any number that have 9 numbers, separated or not by the char `-`
Example:

> 000-000-0000

> 0001110000

Here is my code:

```
 public static String verifyPhones(String phones) {
    Pattern patternValidAllPhones = Pattern.compile("^(((\\d{3}[-]?){2}\\d{4})[ ]+)+$");
    Pattern patternToFindWrongPhones = Pattern.compile("([ ]+((\\d{3}[-]?){2}\\d{4})[ ]+)");

    phones = phones.replaceAll("\\r", " ").replaceAll("\\n", " ").concat(" ");
    Matcher matcherValidAllPhones = patternValidAllPhones.matcher(phones);

    if(!matcherValidAllPhones.matches()) {
      Matcher matcherToFindWrongPhones = patternToFindWrongPhones.matcher(phones);
      return matcherToFindWrongPhones.replaceAll("").trim();
    }

    return "";
  }
```

```
@Test
  public void verifyPhonesTest_whenInvalidPhones_thenReturneInvalidPhones() {

    String invalidPhones1 = "202-555*0125 202-555-0125 202-555-0125 202-555-0125";
    String invalidPhones2 = "202-555-0125202-555-0125 202-555-0125 202-555-0125";
    String invalidPhones3 = "202555*0125 202-555-0125 202-555-0125 202-555-0125";
    String invalidPhones4 = "2025550125 20255501252025550125";

    String result1 = PhonesService.verifyPhones(invalidPhones1);
    String result2 = PhonesService.verifyPhones(invalidPhones2);
    String result3 = PhonesService.verifyPhones(invalidPhones3);
    String result4 = PhonesService.verifyPhones(invalidPhones4);

    assertFalse(result1.isEmpty());
    assertEquals("202-555*0125", result1);

    assertFalse(result2.isEmpty());
    assertEquals("202-555-0125202-555-0125", result2);

    assertFalse(result3.isEmpty());
    assertEquals("202555*0125", result3);

    assertFalse(result4.isEmpty());
    assertEquals("20255501252025550125", result4);
  }
```

Comment: What's the definition of a "valid phone"?

Comment: 9 numbers separated or not by -

Example:
111-111-1111
0005559999 

 , but they come together with space or break of line

Example:

111-111-1111 0005559999 111-111-1111\\n111-111-1111


Obs.: The break of lines, I am removing before and replacing for space.

Comment: As I can see in case of a valid String the numbers in it have to be separated from each other by a space, is that true?

Comment: Yes, it's. If it comes with other thing than space between the numbers it is invalid.
because of that I replace the \\n for spaces before validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I suggest:

If valid numbers have to be separated by a space from each other, then you can first split the String by spaces into pieces, where each piece is going to be a number. And then apply validation pattern on each piece separately. Those pieces that do not match the pattern are going to be invalid numbers.

Here's an example:

```java
private static final Pattern phonePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3}[-]?){2}\\d{4}");

public static List<String> verifyPhones(String phones) {
    String[] numbers = phones.split("\\s+");
    List<String> wrongPhones = new ArrayList<>();
        
    for (String number : numbers) {
        if (!phonePattern.matcher(number).matches()) {
            wrongPhones.add(number);
        }
    }
    return wrongPhones;        
}
```

Note: I've changed the method's signature. Now it returns a `List` of wrong numbers. You do not expect to always have only one invalid number, do you?

Comment: No, I can have more than one, it's better this way.
Thank you, I was stuck in the regex and I didn't see another solution.